# Opposite to "Inverted Selection" with Mustache

Tags: javascript, template-engine, mustache

I'm curious as to whether Mustache has a syntax feature that is the opposite of the "Inverted Selection" syntax `{{^foo}}`.

Let's say we have the data:

```
{
  people: [
    { name: "Alice" },
    { name: "Bob" },
    { name: "Mallory" }
  ]
}
```

And the template:

```
<h3>People</h3>
<ul>
  {{#people}}
    <li>{{name}</li>
  {{/people}}
</ul>
```

If we wanted to add an item if there are no people, we just add something like:

```
{{^people}}<li>No people</li>{{/people}}
```

But in my case I don't want to show the `<h3>` and `<ul>` if there are no people.

A syntax like `{{?people}}` (representing the opposite / boolean negation of `{{^people}}`) would be perfect for this situation, **but does one exist?**

---

Another alternative would be to preprocess the data, adding a value

```
has_people = Boolean(people.length)
```

and using `{{#has_people}}`, but this seems counter-intuitive and against the logic-less (and I use that term lightly) paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution seemed to be to add the functionality myself.

I've forked the Mustache.js repository with the changes required to introduce the `{{? data }}` selector. In English it could be read as 'When true, or there are items within `data`.'

[Repository](https://github.com/DerFlatulator/mustache.js) | [Diff 1](https://github.com/DerFlatulator/mustache.js/commit/2d6e7a9757f491e6417c35838bbda50d32dcd621) | [Diff 2](https://github.com/DerFlatulator/mustache.js/commit/91fe79ea38024350805a44ab93a73fc249a5681c)

Comment: Why not just use Handlebars if you're going through with all this? The functionality is all already there.

Comment: You're probably right. I've used handlebars a little in the past, but for this project I've been using plain Mustache. I've found that it has lead to very clean templates.